# In swift, how to refer to topmost class when my class has subclass of same name

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift:

- How can I assign a topmost `myObject` to the `innerObj` variable?
- Does swift have some sort of namespace operator that lets me create an `myObject` from global namespace?

Consider the code below.

```
//my object that can init with a message=string
class MyObject {
    init(message: String) {
        println(message)
    }
}
//here I define a global works fine
let global = myObject(message: "this works")


//other class
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //defines an inner class with same name
    class MyObject {
        func failsFunction(){
            //cannot invoke initializer for type "ViewController.myObject" with an argument of type (String)
            let innerObj = myObject("how can I refer to the topmost myObject here?")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a note on terminology: That second definition of `myObject` isn't a "subclass", it's an "inner class" or "nested class"

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this, I will update accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One usual way is to bind your outer class into struct. This pattern is quite similar to creating a namespace. You could do it like this

```
struct MyNameSpace {
    class myObject {
        init(message: String) {
            print(message)
        }
    }
}
//here I define a global works fine
let global = MyNameSpace.myObject(message: "this works")


//other class
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //defines a subclass with same name
    class myObject {
        func failsFunction(){
            //cannot invoke initializer for type "ViewController.myObject" with an argument of type (String)
            let innerObj = MyNameSpace.myObject(message: "how can I refer to the topmost myObject here?")
        }
    }

}
```

Then, you could use both the classes and the compiler determines the use cases differently for both.

Answer (score 3):

My first answer would be "don't do that." It's technically legal because the two classes have unique scope, but it's confusing as all hell, and will come back to bite you 6 months from now when you are coming back to this code and don't remember that you have a global class and a child class of ViewController with the same name.

If you are going to ignore that advice, Lou provided your solution: Create a typeAlias at the top level and use that inside your ViewController class so that you can reference the global class inside ViewController.

Secondly, class names should start with an upper-case letter. So `class myObject` should be `class MyObject`. This is a documented convention of the language.

Thirdly, `myObject` is a dreadful name for a class. It doesn't give you any idea what the class is for. Even if this is a learning exercise, you should still follow good coding practices. It trains good habits, and test code has a way of finding itself in real projects, or posted as demo code somewhere, or whatever.

Comment: Yes indeed, it one can avoid it its certainly the right thing to do. Corrected the lower letter :) MyObject well indeed, I understand your point, but for the sake of not changing to much I will leave it be

Answer (score 2):

You need to alias it before you hide it with:

`typealias GlobalMyObject = MyObject`